# js circular dependencies with require

Tags: javascript

How can I remove circular dependencies in JavaScript and don't have a duplicity with using `require('module')` pattern?

Let's have two cases that should be the same:

[image: Two cases]
Left case:

```
// file1.js (depends on file3.js since it uses C2)
class Base {
   add() {
      this.items.push(new C2());
   }
}

// file2.js (depends on file1.js since it uses Base)
class C1 extends Base {
}

// file3.js (depends on file1.js since it uses Base)
class C2 extends Base {
}
```

Introduces circular file dependencies.

Is it generally a bad if I create an instance in a base class?

Right case:

```
// file1.js (no dependency)
class Base {
}

// file2.js (depends on file1.js and file3.js since it uses Base and C2)
class C1 extends Base {
   add() {
      this.items.push(new C2());
   }
}

// file3.js (depends on file1.js since it uses Base)
class C2 extends Base {
   add() {
      this.items.push(new C2());
   }
}
```

It does not introduce circular file dependencies, but duplicates code. The method is the same on the two places. Think about a longer method here not just one line method.

Comment: Es6 classes are a nice feature. Though, before you mess up your app you may have a read why it is not advised: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a#.pxkzvn9or

Comment: After alot of issues, I settled on only having one-way dependencies. So the base 'class' should not use one of its 'subclasses. And the subclasses should require any siblings they use. So C1 using C2 should be ok, as long as it explicitly mentions C2 as a dependency.  Also, require should take care of duplicity, since all it'll do is pass around a reference to the same module you require. In the case of the add() method, why not mixin a seperate prototype into the prototype of C1 and C2 so they both inherit from Base and from the prototype that creates the 'add' method.

Comment: Nice and agree with the functional point of view, however using a language construct (a class) looks somehow cleaner in front of eyes. Where would you move the add function and how would you mixin it together with using the classes to be still clean and easy?